# Issue related to pandas to_csv function applied to grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with two variables in it: a string variable `str1` and a floating point numerical variable `fp1`. I group that DataFrame like so:

```
dfg = df.groupby(pandas.qcut(df['fp1'],4,labels=['g1','g2','g3','g4']))
```

I want to write out the grouped results to a csv file. When I try:

```
dfg.to_csv('dfg.csv')
```

the csv file contains observations only for group `g4`.  How can I get the `to_csv` method to write out the whole grouped DataFrame `dfg`?

Comment: I would recheck your question. What's the `type` of your `dfg`. `Groupby` doesn't even have a `to_csv` method.

Comment: The object type of `dfg` : `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x28b3a3cc>`   -- why would it even write out `g4` group data?

Comment: this will raise starting in 0.13, you need to ``apply`` to your groupby to get back a dataframe, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html

Comment: Thanks for responses Tom and Jeff. While I wait for pandas to be updated on my system, I'm using the following workaround:
    `outfile = open('output.csv', 'a') #next line
    
    for name, group in dfg: #next line
        group.to_csv(outfile, header=False)`